# How to split this file into several files in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I want some files out of the way in my node.js server because I feel like they clutter it. Any idea how I can accomplish that?

I want one file to contain things like this
Ideally something like this would work ( where the contents of the file could just be appended to the top of the file, or whatever, by some sort of magical require statement)

settings.js file

```
/* Defines a bunch of global variables and settings */
/* I understand global isa  bad practice but I want this clutter out of the main server file */


express = require("express"); // Express JS
logfmt = require("logfmt"); // Heroku key-value logger
mongoose = require('mongoose'); // DB simplifier
passport = require('passport'); // Authentication
flash    = require('connect-flash'); // Flash Messages
port = Number(process.env.PORT || 5000); // Locally uses port 5000, else uses port of server
configDB      = require('./config/database.js');
cookieParser  = require('cookie-parser');
bodyParser    = require('body-parser');
session       = require('express-session');

app = express(); //Express for server
```

Main server file

/**************************************************
 ** SERVER 
 **************************************************/

```
var settings = require("./settings");

/* GLOBAL VARIABLE FOR THE SERVER. MAYBE BAD PRACTICE IDK YOLO */ 
server        = require('http').createServer(app);
util          = require("util");
io  = require("socket.io").listen(server);
 _settings = new settings();
//socket;   // Socket controller idk tbh
/* END GLOBAL VARIABLES */
....
```

Comment: You should learn to use `var` in front of your variable declarations so you're not declaring accidental globals.  This is considered bad practice in Javascript because it can lead to conflicts between variable names which the whole nodejs module system is designed to prevent if you use normal module variables declared with `var`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it!

/* Defines a bunch of global variables and settings */

settings.js

```
module.exports 

= {
  load : function() {
           express = require("express"); // Express JS
           logfmt = require("logfmt"); // Heroku key-value logger
           mongoose = require('mongoose'); // DB simplifier
           passport = require('passport'); // Authentication
           flash    = require('connect-flash'); // Flash Messages
           port = Number(process.env.PORT || 5000); // Locally uses port 5000, else uses port of server
           configDB      = require('./config/database.js');
           cookieParser  = require('cookie-parser');
           bodyParser    = require('body-parser');
           session       = require('express-session');

           app = express(); //Express for server
         }
};
```

server.js

```
var settings = require("./settings");
settings.load();
```

// :D

Comment: except for the port 5000, none of those are settings.  what else could you call it?

Comment: prep_server.js? config.js ? app.js? what do you think?

Comment: It is really not advisable to be using globals for all your module variables.  This can create conflicts/clashes between modules.  I would not recommend this method at all.  You could return an object from `.load()` and then get all the module variables from that object, but I think you'll find that the way it was originally is easier.